# How use WebView in Qt 5.12 without installing Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: visual-studio, qt, webview, qt-quick, qtquickcontrols2

I Have **Qt 5.12.6** And **Visual Studio 2019** on Windows 10 64-bit.

Now I have a problem with `WebView`.My project worked well when I had visual studio 2017.but I uninstalled that and Now I have visual Studio 2019,Now `WebView` don't load the page and in Windows I see the below in Application output,when I push the `PaymentPage.qml` in `StackView` that contains `WebView`.

> No WebView plug-in found!

I don't have any problem when I had Visual Studio 2017.How can I solve my problem without installing Visual Studio 2017 again?

**In Android I don't have any problem**